# Zero value output from lsim in comparison to dlsim

Tags: python, scipy, simulation

to learn more about scipy, I'm trying to compare the continuous and discrete versions of a simple state space model using the lsim and dlsim methods. I am finding that my scipy dlsim agrees with the lsim and dlsim output from MATLAB, however, the scipy lsim output array is all zeros. I'm not spotting the issue based on the scipy documentation but feel it must be a simple error on my part and looking for any words of wisdom. Thanks!

**Python Code**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import StateSpace as ss
from scipy.signal import cont2discrete as c2d
from scipy.signal import lsim, dlsim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[-1, -5], [6, -1]])
B = np.array([[1], [0]])
C = np.array([[0, 1]])
D = np.array([[0]])
dt = 0.01

sys_c = ss(A, B, C, D)
sys_d = c2d((A, B, C, D), dt)

T = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
U = np.sin(T) * 0.1
tC, yC, xC = lsim(sys_c, U, T)
tD, yD, xD = dlsim(sys_d, U, T)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.plot(T, U, label='Input')
ax1.set_title('Scipy lsim vs dlsim Comparison')
ax1.set(ylabel='Input')
ax1.grid()
ax2.plot(tC, yC, 'b', label='Continuous')
ax2.plot(tD, yD, 'r', label='Discrete')
ax2.set(xlabel= 'Time (sec)', ylabel='Output')
ax2.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**MATLAB Code**

```
x0 = [0; 0]; %initial condition of system states

A = [-1, -5; 6, -1];
B = [1; 0];
C = [0 1];
D = 0;
sys_c = ss(A, B, C, D);
sys_d = c2d(sys_c, 0.01)

t = 0:0.01:10;
u = sin(t) * 0.1;
[y_c, x_c] = lsim(sys_c, u, t, x0);
[y_d, x_d] = lsim(sys_d, u);

figure;
plot(t, u)

figure
plot(t, y_c, 'r'); hold on;
plot(t, y_d, 'b')
legend('Response','Input')
```

[image]

***NOTE:*** MATLAB lsim and dlsim traces overlap in figure